# Text search on any document value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, text-search

Let's say I have a MongoDB document like this:

```
{
    "_id"  : ObjectId("xxxx-xxxx"),
    "name" : "judge dredd",
    "docs" : {
        "readme-1" : "Please do!",
        "readme-2" : "Go ahead...",
        "readme-n" : "foo bar"
    }
}
```

How may I create a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/#index-feature-text) that can index and search any of the values of the object `docs`, but nothing else?

The issues that that the keys of the `docs` document may be anything, and I don't know what they are before hand.

The [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes) mention a wildcard operator:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )
```

but that indexes *every String* including `name` which I don't want. The standard way seems to use a dot property:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "docs.readme-1":"text", "docs.readme-2":"text, ... } )
```

But as mentioned, the object keys may be anything and I don't know them upfront.

If not possible, is there a better way of re-arranging my data document so it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create another model with a reference of that object you want e.g:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const idSchema = new Schema ({
    name:{type:string,required:true},
    documentReferenced:{Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'documentReferenced'}
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Id ', idSchema);
```

then when you need to call your documentReferenced or whatever you call it, you just can do the following

```
 Id.findOne({name:req.body.name}).populate('documentReferenced').exec(( err, document)=> {
    your code here....
 });
```

I dont'n really know if there is another better way to do what you need but this could be a nice workaround.

Comment: I like your idea splitting the document into two, one that holds the usual data (e.g. `name`), and the other that contains just the `docs` field and a reference back to the orgininal document. That way I can create a wildcard search index and just have `docs` indexed.